# How to perform Many to Many Relationship Filter Query

Tags: mysql, sql, many-to-many

I want to perform a query in MySQL based on a filter. First of all, the two tables that will be used in the query are the following:

Equipment:

| Field | Type |
| --- | --- |
| Id | PK, Integer |
| Name | Varchar(50) |

Recipe:

| Field | Type |
| --- | --- |
| Id | PK, Integer |
| Name | Varchar(50) |

The relationship between the two tables is Many-to-Many, so there is a pivot table.

The filter is as follows, you have an array of recipe id, for example:

```
recipeIds = [1,2,3]
```

The current data:

Equipments:

| Id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | A |
| 101 | B |
| 102 | C |
| 103 | D |
| 104 | E |
| 105 | F |

Recipes:

| Id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Recipe 1 |
| 2 | Recipe 2 |
| 3 | Recipe 3 |
| 4 | Recipe 4 |
| 7 | Recipe 7 |
| 8 | Recipe 8 |
| 9 | Recipe 9 |

Pivot Table:

| EquipmentId | RecipeId |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | 1 |
| 100 | 4 |
| 101 | 1 |
| 101 | 2 |
| 103 | 9 |
| 103 | 7 |
| 104 | 1 |
| 104 | 2 |
| 104 | 3 |
| 105 | 1 |
| 105 | 2 |
| 105 | 3 |
| 105 | 8 |

Then the query should return the equipment that is present (or owns) to the recipes mentioned in `recipeIds`:

Query Result (Equipments):

| Id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 104 | E |
| 105 | F |

The other equipments should not appear, here the reasons:

| Equipment | Reason |
| --- | --- |
| A | Only recipe 1 is present, but not all 3 recipes mentioned |
| B | Only recipe 1 and 2 is present, but not all 3 recipes mentioned |
| C | Does not have any recipe |
| D | Does not have any of the mentioned recipes |

I don't know how to perform the query. I hope your help.

Comment: I'm confused... What about you post a few rows of data example for both tables and maybe skip the `JSON` for the time being. Focus on how to get the result in pure MySQL then only convert to your desired `JSON` output. And by the way, just try to write a query and implement your condition there. It doesn't have to be a working query.. one that you can illustrate what you're after should be enough.

Comment: Ok @FaNo_FN, i'm edited the post

Comment: So `Pivot` is a real table in a database, is that correct? Not a table generated by query?

Comment: Yes, is a real table

Comment: If like that, it seems that you only need `Pivot` for the `recipes` checking and `JOIN` it with `Equipment` table to get `Name`.

Comment: Something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT P.EquipmentID, E.Name
FROM Pivot P 
JOIN Equipments E ON P.EquipmentID=E.Id
WHERE E.RecipeId IN (1,2,3) 
GROUP BY P.EquipmentID, E.Name
HAVING COUNT(*)=3;
```

1. Join `Pivot` and `Equipments` table.
2. Add condition `WHERE E.RecipeId IN (1,2,3)`.
3. Add `GROUP BY P.EquipmentID, E.Name`.
4. Add `HAVING COUNT(*)=3;` for any group of `P.EquipmentID, E.Name` that occur 3 times; effectively matches your condition of *"only EquipmentID that appear in Receipe 1,2,3"*.

[Here's a fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=28b90c20a1c45b8e3a01136f3ceaedd9)